# get innerText with jQuery instead of innerHTML

Tags: jquery, innertext

I have a figcaption and i would like the text from it.
This is what it looks like in the element inspector in chrome.
For some reason the 'innerHTML' starts with a return and then a lot of spaces. The 'innerText' however looks good so i'm interested in that.

[image]

Online I see I have to use the `text()` method to get the innerText but it seems to give the innerHTML:

```
console.log("-"+$(this).find("figcaption").text()+"-");
```

[image]

So how can I get to the innerText?

Comment: I think it is indeed returning the innerText.  Notice that there are no html tags in the resulting output.

Comment: You could use `replace` after `text()`, like: `.replace(/( ){2,}/gi, "red")`. It will remove all extra spaces.

Comment: @Kolban But there are no spaces in the innerText in the dom.

Comment: @klauskpm nice, this brings me somewhere. I only have a return at the start. Could I also get rid of that. And this is just modifying the innerHTML instead of the innerText right?

Comment: Well, `text()` is supposed to return `innerText`. You are also receving `return` as part of the text?

Comment: I think text() returns the DOM text node while the innerText property is the calculated cleanup for display of the text node.

Answer (score 5):

When you create an HTML element such as:

```
<p>Hello          World</p>
```

When that is rendered by the browser, whitespace is collapsed by default.  The result will be "Hello World".  That collapsing of the data happens at browser rendering time.  The DOM model contained within the browser maintains the actual text including any white spaces contained within it.  As such, what you see on the screen may not be the same as the data contained within the DOM.

The white space stripped data is available via the DOM property called "innerText".

A [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/fokewi/1/edit?html,js,console,output) sample showing the data has been supplied.

The demonstration code is basically:

**HTML**

```
<p id="here">Hello      World</p>
<button>Show</button>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    console.log("text: " + $("#here").text());
    console.log("innerText: " + $("#here").prop("innerText"));
  });
});
```

The console will log:

```
text: Hello      World
innerText: Hello World
```

From your original question, the use of the `text()` method returns the DOM data while the use of `prop("innerText")` returns the calculated `innerText` value that the browser built.

Comment: If I look in the dom (see screenshot OP), then innerHTML has those whitespace, innerText however has not. So is assume innerText is ok without having the need to edit.
In case it matters, it's the text from adding photo's to tumblr. So those added whitespaces make no sense anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  Ive updated the answer with more details and a sample.