# jQuery.text() retrieves all spaces and line returns from HTML element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have some text displayed in a HTML table cell. The text includes some spaces and other line returns that are **not** visible when I look at the HTML output on my screen (just like in the snippet below).

Using `jQuery.text()` method, all these spaces and line returns are *copied* along with the text.

What should I use to grab what is *visually* displayed by my browser (as shown in the *Expected output* textarea)?

```js
$(function() {
  let str = $('#address').text();
  $('textarea.paste').val(str);
});
```

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td id="address">
        Some word<br>

        Some
        more
        words
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<div>
  <code>jQuery.text()</code> output:<br>
  <textarea class="paste" rows="7"></textarea>
</div>
<div>
  Expected output:<br>
  <textarea rows="7">Some word&#13;Some more words</textarea>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Add `white-space: pre;` to your `td` and you will see that the return from `jQuery.text()` is actually correct. You can remove all none `br` linebreaks of course, if that is what you seek.

Comment: Aparently you simply want to replace the "new lines" with spaces - check out this question on so: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9849754/how-can-i-replace-newlines-line-breaks-with-spaces-in-javascript

Comment: @lain nope. That has the opposite effect to what I am after (it *visually* displays the text on 5 lines, just as it is in the HTML).

Comment: @Kathara nope, that does not work. Have you tried it?

Comment: @Lain I haven't said that the `text()` method was wrong. Here is my question again: *What should I use to grab what is visually displayed by my browser?*

Comment: Right. Let's try again. My question is *What should I use to grab what is visually displayed by my browser?* That is: 2 lines of text, not 5! Line 1 : *Some word* and Line 2 : *Some more words*. In between these 2 lines is a line break. Just **as displayed by my browser**.

Comment: Use `$('#address').html().replaceAll(/\s+/g, " ").replaceAll(/<br>/g, "\n")`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [get innerText with jQuery instead of innerHTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26720490/get-innertext-with-jquery-instead-of-innerhtml)

Comment: jQuery's `.text()` is the same as [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent), not the same as `.innerText`

Comment: @MrUpsidown no I did not, but there was no attempt to try it from the original question. Also at the time I did not know that `.text()` already replaces `<br>`-tags to "\n\n".  And I also did not know that `.prop('innerText')` actually gets the correct result of this. Learned something new, thx ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can read the `innerText` property:

```js
$(function() {
  let str = $('#address').prop('innerText');
  $('textarea.paste').val(str);
});
```

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td id="address">
        Some word<br>

        Some
        more
        words
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<div>
  <code>innerText</code> output:<br>
  <textarea class="paste" rows="7"></textarea>
</div>
<div>
  Expected output:<br>
  <textarea rows="7">Some word&#13;Some more words</textarea>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for actually *reading* my question (unlike many people here). And for your perfect answer!